# Remove unused file versions

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

I'm using latest version of Concrete5 8.3.1

How do I automatically delete unused image/file versions?

I have more than 4000 images on the website each with 5-6+ versions and sometimes 30. So the old versions use 10 times more disk space. And removing them manually from File Manager will take ages to finish

How to delete the unused versions from the database and also from the thumbnails folders?

I tried searching for an add-on or a job but didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "unused" as in every version of a file that is not the currenct/active one? Or you'd like to scrape all pages/blocks etc. to see if a file is actually used? The latter would be quite impossible, the first doable.

I do have an Add-On developed that can delete leftovers, but not former/unused versions of files (yet). Could build that in, but will take me a few weeks to complete since I got other deadlines right now.

Comment: Yes it's the first, I meant image versions that are not active/current. It would be great if you let me know when you develop this feature on the add-on. Is the add-on published on Concrete5? If so what's it called so I download it?

Comment: It's this one: [Website Optimizer](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/website-optimizer/). EDIT: Just added this option in, please do make a backup of your website & database first in **all situations** before optimizing (in case you do want to roll back or something went wrong).

Comment: Thank you, I have couple of question before buying the add-on I will post them on the support section of the addon